# Как правильно сделать url запрос

Tags: python

Мне необходимо сделать запрос вида:

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen("https://graphhopper.com/api/1/route?point=51.131%2C12.414&point=48.224%2C3.867&vehicle=car&locale=ru&key=my_key")
```

Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
data = (('point', '51.131,12.414'), ('point', '48.224,3.867'), ('vehicle', 'car'), ('locale', 'ru'), ('key', 'my_key'))
response = urllib.request.urlopen("https://graphhopper.com/api/1/route", data)
```

но не выходит...
Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Одно сказать могу точно, что данные нужно отправлять в json формате
Попробуйте так:

```
data = {'point': '51.131,12.414', 'point': '48.224,3.867', 'vehicle': 'car', 'locale': 'ru', 'key': 'my_key'}
response = urllib.request.urlopen("https://graphhopper.com/api/1/route", data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Заработало через requests вот так:

```
url = "https://graphhopper.com/api/1/route"
payload = (('point', '51.131,12.414'), ('point', '48.224,3.867'), ('vehicle', 'car'), ('locale', 'ru'), ('key', 'my_key'))
r = requests.get(url, params=payload)
```